# Specify Vector Error Correction Model with different lagged effects?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, estimation, lags, vector-error-correction-model

I'm fitting a Vector Error Correction Model. The general form is like this:

$$\Delta y_t = A_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{t-1} A_1 \Delta y_{t-i} + \lambda EC_t + \nu_t$$

In which $EC_t$ is the error correction term. For instance, let's consider the endogenous variables in the model as House values $(H_t)$, Interest rates $(I_t)$, and Population $(P_t)$. Arguably, $P_t$ won't be specified as dependent variable in the specification of cointegration equations. The main interest is to modelling and forecasting $H_t$ on $I_t$ and $P_t$.

I believe that the effect of $P_t$ is much more lagged than the effect of $I_t$. That is, changes in the interest rate will have more immediate effect on property prices than changes in population. If that is the case, which of the following would be the better specification?

(i) Use the original $P_t$ series. Expectedly there will be a larger number of lags in the model.

(ii) Construct lagged $P_{t-h}$ series, in which $h$ is the lag argued to begin to have effect on $H_t$. For example, I can construct $P_{t-12}$, $P_{t-24}$, etc. These lagged series are then used in the modelling with $H_t$ and $I_t$.

I'd also appreciate if you can point to some further reference.