# VECM and heteroskedasticity

Tags: time-series, stata, heteroscedasticity, vector-error-correction-model

So, I am trying to run a regression that requires me to log and take the first differences of it to render stationary. That is why I am using VECM.

I ran the diagnostic tests, and everything is fine except heteroskedasticity. So, I tried to use weights and also `vce(robust)` in Stata and it fixed the problem. However, I have one question. Should I run let's say `d.log(y)=d.log(x1)+d.log(x2) vce(robust)` or only `log(y)=log(x1)+log(x2) vce(robust)`?

Comment: I don't use Stata, but none of the options look right if you have a VECM in mind. Is `log(y)=log(x1)+log(x2)` not the same as $\ln(y_t)=\beta_0+\beta_1\ln(x_{1,t})+\beta_2\ln(x_{2,t})+\varepsilon_t$ while adding `d.` would add $\Delta$ in front? A VECM is formulated in first differences, so with $\Delta$, but it contains *lagged* variables on the right hand side plus a lagged error correction term.

Comment: Yes VECM is formulated in the first difference. What I am unsure of now is when testing for heteroskedasticity using the robust standard errors function should I just regress it in the logarithmic form or with the first difference variables?

Comment: Check the equation in this recent post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/597350. This is what you want, with $y_t$ replaced by $\ln(y_t)$. I do not know how to achieve that in Stata.